# How to calculate individual mask area of the objects in Mask Rcnn

Tags: python, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I created my own dataset, which is to identify a particular type of crop in a field. Mask RCNN creates a polygon mask over that object. There are about 17 different objects in the image, so MaskRCNN creates a mask over the 17 objects. But I'm not able to find the area of each masks.

I found a way, but I'm not sure whether it is correct.
I have added this code to inspect_balloon_model.ipynb:

r['masks].shape[-1] = 17

```
for i in range(r['masks'].shape[-1]):
    mask = r['masks'][:, :, i]
    image[mask] = 255
    image[~mask] = 0
    unique, counts = np.unique(image, return_counts=True)
    mask_area = counts[1] / (counts[0] + counts[1])
    print(counts[1])
```

Here is counts[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTdnz.png) is the area of the individual mask. Is this correct?

**EDIT**:
r['masks'].shape ---> (8170, 6000, 17);
Original image shape --> (8170, 6000, 3)

**Sample image:**

[image: cropped sample image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks correct, but it's IMO very convoluted.
A simpler version would be:

```
positive_pixel_count = mask.sum() # assumes binary mask (True == 1)
h, w = mask.shape[1:3] # assumes NHWC data format, adapt as needed
area = positive_pixel_count / (w*h)
```

Comment: Here mask.shape is same as the shape of original image

Comment: You mention Mask RCNN. In that network, predicted masks are per-instance and relative to the bounding box. If you're talking about a different type of mask, please clarify in the question and provide examples of how the mask looks like

Comment: I've shared a sample image. added the shape of masks

Comment: Am I correct to assume that each mask is a binary image white in one of the colored areas and black everywhere else? If so, your area calculation and mine are equivalent, because `counts[0]` is the number of black pixels, so summing `counts[0]` and `counts[1]` gives the total number of pixels (i.e., `w*h`). Is this not the area you seek?